# Loading social widgets from ajax .load()'ed content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an issue where I'm trying to show a popup that uses jQuery's `.load()` function to populate a div with content from a separate page. Within this separate page there are facebook and twitter widgets.

Each widget requires its own js code. FB recommends placing their js code after the opening `<body>` tag, and twitters code appears to be happy placed before the ending `</body>` tag. This separate page works fine when viewed directly.

I'm using the following function to load the separate page into a hidden div;

### JS

```
function load_overlay(url)
{
    var wrapper = $('.popup_wrapper');
    var content = $('.popup_wrapper .popup_content');
    content.html(''); // clear out the content first
    content.load(url, function() {

        $('.popup_bg').fadeIn(400, function() {
            wrapper.fadeIn();
            wrapper.animate({
                "top" : $(window).scrollTop() + 360
            });
        });

    });
}
load_overlay('/social-popup #main');
```

The problem here is that (from what I've read) is that `.load()` when using a `#` selector strips out all js and doesn't execute it, so none of the social widgets load when called via `.load()`

I've tried including the js for fb and twitter in the html page this is being called from hoping that would fix it, however nothing changed.

How can I get the JS for these widgets to load for my ajax loaded content?

Comment: Why do you load `/social-popup #main` with `#main`?

Comment: because I only want to load a small section of that page. I'd note this also doesn't appear to work if I remove `#main` from it

Comment: Without `#main` load will execute any javascript code: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I had read the same earlier and when testing adding an `alert` this works. However both social widgets still do not load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a good solution to this while using the JS implementations of each social widget.

To work around the issue, I've resorted to using the `<iframe>` implementation of the social widgets. This completely removes the issue of `<script>` tags being removed.

The only minor caveat is that twitters iframe implementation doesn't support customisation of the width and or height of their buttons, but this is a fair compromise.